# How to set password for vendor and customer in nopCommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I have setup nopCommerce on my system.

When I create a vendor using the admin account, there is no option to enter a password for vendor.

After creating a new vendor, how can we login with the recently created new vendor? I ask because there is no option for password

How do I set a password for the vendor and customer accounts.

Answer (score 0):

> *When I create a vendor using the admin account, there is no option to enter a password for vendor*

A vendor in nopCommerce is sort of profile. It isn't a user ie. customer. Once you created a vendor then you have to associate it with a user (customer).

> After creating a new vendor, how can we login with the recently created new vendor?

you can't out of the box. But you can customize this functionality as such that whenever you create a vendor, in background you can create a user with that same name and add it to vendor role and assign to this (newly created) vendor.

> How do I set a password for the vendor and customer accounts

the asnwer is same as above. here is how you can create a password http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/Admin/Customer/Create. there is a password field.